# Debugging AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'save' from ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error, python-2.7

I Keep getting this error message when i run the code below, can anyone tell me why?

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\GEP_662\Final_Project\Final_Project1.py", line 65, in <module>
    result3.save('C:\GEP_662\\Final_Project\\satersym')
AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Code:

```
import arcpy

rasterLayer = "C:\GEP_662\\Final_Project\\TOC_IDW1.lyr"
rasterLayerName = 'TOC_IDW_LYR'

# Apply the symbology from the symbology layer to the input layer
outputraster = arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(rasterLayerName, rasterLayer)
outputraster.save('C:\GEP_662\\Final_Project\\rastersym')

print "symbology update done"
```

Comment: When adding samples, remember to select the entire sample and press the {} button to give it proper formatting.

Comment: @DWynne, I did select the entire sample is something missing? thanks I did not know about the {} button

Comment: No worries now. @dmahr made an edit for you. :)

Comment: There are several issues here: 1) your pathnames are formatted incorrectly, 2) you are using an improper method to "save" the results, 3) both `rasterLayerName` and `rasterLayer` need to be layers.  Try formatting your script following the Esri help page example: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006n000000

Comment: Problem solved, I i was not seeing anything because my path location was incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geoprocessing tools (with the exception of Spatial Analyst tools) return a [Result](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) object, which is what `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management` returns here. It doesn't have a `save` method. You may be getting this mixed up with a `MapDocument` or `Layer` object.